# how to delete array value from table in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I had set of array had been push and display correctly.now i want to delete from the table locally .sorry if my logic is wrong.Am new to javascript and jquery.correct my code it useful to learn from u all

here my code:

```
function deleteowner(val)
{
    alert("val number=====>"+val);
    var deletevalue = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('rowdel' + val).innerHTML);
    alert("val==>  "+JSON.stringify(deletevalue));

    if(deletevalue==val){
        deletevalue.splice(val,1);
    }

}
```

[Refer my code](http://jsfiddle.net/senthil4040/hxpg3ta3/)

Comment: [Refer this link][1]


  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/senthil4040/hxpg3ta3/

Comment: do you want to remove table row?

Comment: yes.when i click of delete button

Comment: Assuming this is an array, `splice()` the element you don't want **and** update the table on the screen. In other-words you need to remake the table and show it.

Comment: @Spencer Wieczorek .i want to delete a particular row on my delete onclick event in a table it possible please provide sample it use ful to learn from u

Comment: @user3607180 I think the answers below both do a good job, take a look at them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this  http://jsfiddle.net/hxpg3ta3/5/

```
$("#Mytabel").find('input[value=Delete]').on('click',function(){
$(this).parent().parent().remove();
});
```

Comment: thanks for time could u able to remove a row in table with sample

Comment: these array values are your tds actually within that tr you want to delete . You got my point ?

Comment: you want to implement this on click event ?

Comment: @user3607180 is this what you wanted ?

Comment: ya ,but in my side it not working checking on it.thanks for u r time

Comment: @user3607180  Pleasure :)

Comment: I edited my code ..With the previous one ...the edit functionality was also getting affected ..But now this work exactly you want ..Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way -For Example,

```
var cont = 0;

function addRow(array) {
    $("#Mytabel").append("<tr id=row+" + array.Id + "><td>" + array.Name + "</td><td>" + array.Cost + "</td><td><input type='button' class='delete' value='DELETE'/></td></tr>");
}

$(function () {
    $("#btnADD").click(function () {
        var vet = {
            Id: cont,
            Name: "jan",
            Cost: 15
        };
        cont++;
        addRow(vet);
    });
    $('#Mytabel').on('click', '.delete', function () {
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    })
});
```

Demo:- http://jsfiddle.net/UMVyQ/